# Make UIWebView behave exactly as Safari

Tags: ios, swift3

I am building a webview app that should load a specific website using `UIWebView`, but the webview doesn't behave as Safari.
A lot of links don't open, and file download and preview doesn't work, also, some JavaScript doesn't work.

Is there a way to make my web view behave exactly as Safari browser?

Comment: Why are you using `UIWebView` and not `SFSafariViewController` ? Provide more info about your use case and code if you can. Could be an issue with UIWebView or your website.

Comment: I don't want the top and bottom Navigation bars in SFSafariViewController

Comment: What links aren't opening ? Local file resources ? Remote links ? Have you debugged the javascript code ?

Comment: Mainly all links that open external apps, such as sharing links to Whatsapp or facebook and viewing PDF files etc.. Also java-script dialogs such as warning dialogs don't appear.
All these work normally on Safari browser, but not on my WKWebView